# Excel 2013: VBA Code to filter worksheet data from multiple listbox selections

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, multi-select, autofilter

I've spent 3 days now searching for a solution and I know I'm close, but I just don't get my issue and why it is happening.

First of all, I have a spreadsheet which contains staff names (column A, starting from row 5) and resource planning data (abbreviations of projects) from column B to HG. Each coloumn -except for column A- represents 1 day of a calendar (column headers are dates).

[image: worksheet with data]

I also have a user form containing 3 listboxes (multiselect). LB1 = staff names, LB2 = project abbreviations, LB3 don't matter for now. I also have 3 buttons on this user form, 1 to reset the LB selections, 1 to apply the filter to the spreadsheet and 1 to reset the filter on the spreadsheet.

My code for resetting the LB selections and the filter on the spreadsheet works just fine. The one to apply the filter just won't work the way it is supposed to. The code for this button so far looks as follows (just trying to handle 1 LB for now):

```
' Apply filter to spreadsheet
Private Sub CB_FilterActive_Click()
    Dim arrMitarbeiter() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer

    count = 1
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            ReDim Preserve arrMitarbeiter(count)
            arrMitarbeiter(count) = ListBox1.List(i)
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("Einsatzplan").UsedRange.Cells.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(arrMitarbeiter)
End Sub
```

Here's the thing:

hitting the "apply filter button" makes all rows containing data in the spreadsheet dissapear. When I try to debug the code, I see that the array for the autofilter gets populated correctly in regards to LB selections. When I hit the dropdown of the filter applied on the worksheet and go to "textfilter -> equals" and have a look at the populated filter criteria, it's right there. It just won't show the respective rows. I tried a lot of stuff and I just don't know where the problem is. Additionaly, I'm just a VBA beginner trying to figure things out. So any help would be much appreciated (as well for the case when I want to combine selections of all 3 listboxes to hand it to the autofilter)!

Sincerely,
moshpit

**EDIT:**

This is what my current code looks like, rewrote it to be sure about the algorithm. I also debugged the whole thing. Funny thing is: during debugging (while 1 item in the `listbox1` is selected), the array contains this exact value. After applying the filter and going to the `filter options dropdown -> textfilter -> equals`, there is no value in there, which makes me assume that this is why it hides all rows. But how come the value is in the array and doesn't get applied to the filter afterwards? Also, `Field:=` should be an optional parameter regarding to the Microsoft documentation, but when I leave that out, it gives me a runtime error (error# 1004: Can't execute AutoFilter method of range object).

```
Option Explicit

' Apply Filter to Sheet
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim x() As String, r() As String, k() As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, s As Integer

    ReDim x(0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter

    ' Filter Array for ListBox1
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            x(UBound(x)) = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
            ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    If UBound(x) <> 0 Then
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=x, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) - 1)
    End If

    ReDim r(0)

    ' Filter Array for ListBox2
    For j = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(j) = True Then
            r(UBound(r)) = Me.ListBox2.List(j)
            ReDim Preserve r(UBound(r) + 1)
        End If
    Next j
    If UBound(r) <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve r(UBound(r) - 1)
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B1 : HG1").AutoFilter , Criteria1:=r, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    ReDim k(0)

    ' Filter Array for ListBox3
    For s = 0 To ListBox3.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox3.Selected(s) = True Then
            k(UBound(k)) = Me.ListBox3.List(s)
            ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) + 1)
        End If
    Next s
    If UBound(k) <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) - 1)
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").AutoFilter , Criteria1:=k, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Reset Filter Mask
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iCount1 As Integer
    Dim iCount2 As Integer
    Dim iCount3 As Integer

    For iCount1 = 0 To Me!ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        Me!ListBox1.Selected(iCount1) = False
    Next iCount1

    For iCount2 = 0 To Me!ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        Me!ListBox2.Selected(iCount2) = False
    Next iCount2

    For iCount3 = 0 To Me!ListBox3.ListCount - 1
        Me!ListBox3.Selected(iCount3) = False
    Next iCount3
End Sub

' Delete Filter from Sheet
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to get a range different from `UsedRange`? I suppose `UsedRange` takes cells from row 1. And if you have empty rows between 1 and 5, the filter will probably show some weird behavior. I should consider trying `Range("A5:HG")`.

Comment: I already tried a different, manually defined range. This doesnt change anything at all.

Comment: If your goal is not exactly to learn VBA. Consider also using a `Pivot Table`. (Insert / Pivot table). It automatically filters and counts a lot of things, sometimes its way easier than doing VBA.

Comment: Pivot Tables wont work for me. And yes, I actually do want to learn VBA.

Comment: Found your answer down there. If I could suggest, I'd keep a list of names in a sheet, and have a second sheet with only three columns (name, date, project), where I add names, projects and dates, one date per row (names can repeat, dates can repeat, projects can repeat). That way, you are able to use a pivot table (which I always prefer over coding)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in there:

1 - `arrMitarbeiter` is already an array as you defined it in `Dim arrMitarbeiter() As Variant`

So, you cannot pass `Array(arrMitarbeiter)` to the filter, pass only `arrMitarbeiter` instead.

2 - If you dont use the `xlFilterValues` operator, it will filter only the last item of the array, so add this operator.

Fix just this line (i made it two lines just for reading):

```
Worksheets("Einsatzplan").UsedRange.Cells.AutoFilter 
     field:=1, Criteria1:=arrMitarbeiter, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: I just recognized that if I set the filter manually (not through the user form) and then enter a filter value into the "textfilter -> equals -> value" from the dropdown menu of the filter options, it'll filter correctly. What might be the issue here? The whole column is formatted as text. Looks like something's screwed up, but I don't get what it is.

Comment: I also debugged the whole thing. Funny thing is: during debugging (while 1 item in the listbox is selected), the array contains this exact value. After applying the filter and going to the filter options dropdown -> textfilter -> equals, there is no value in there, which makes me assume that this is why it hides all rows. But how come the value is in the array and doesn't get applied to the filter afterwards?

Comment: Did you make the changes I suggested? They work (tested) If you have an empty value, and that empty value is the last in your array, then the result of the filter will be empty.

Comment: Yes, I did try this, didn't change anything to the better. I added my current code to the OP, which I referred to in my last comment. Maybe you can help me out with this one.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that all indexing in VBA is 1-based, not zero based. You work with a zerobased array but you compare to a 1-based list.

Comment: I don't see why you think I do compare the array to a 1-based list. Is it because lists in VBA are indexed starting with 1? Or because I start at 0?

Comment: Ok, tested here and the list is 0-based, so no problem with that. But did you notice in `ListBox1` you redim the arrey only after applying the filter? While the other ones are redimed before. (Without redim you have an empty value a the end of the array).

Comment: That's just a snapshot of the code. I'm just working on `ListBox1` currently, and it doesn't work as intended if I take it the other way around like in `ListBox2` code. Tried all kinds of different things, it just won't work and I just don't get why -.-